# JavaScript - Functions as objects

Tags: javascript, function, object

The concept of functions being objects in JavaScript would be ok with me if I could understand the following question. I have searched around and looked into the javascript engine to try and find the answer, but no explanation I've found so far sits well in my mind...

An object like the one below is understandably layed out in a hash map type of construct.

```
var person = {
    firstName:"John",
    lastName:"Doe",
    age:50,
    eyeColor:"blue"
};
```

However, to say this is also an object is where I get stuck:

```
var name = function () {
    alert ('name');
}
```

1. In terms of memory, how is this function stored?
2. Are the statements inside the "hash map" of a function layed out in an execute order? So each property is called upon after the other?

I'm probably missing something or visualising something wrong.

Thanks.

P.S

To clear up question 2,

Say I have an if statement inside my function... will that be stored in a property accessible through one of its properties?

Comment: Why do people down-vote good thought provoking questions? Probably because they cant come up with a 1 line answer before everyone else. That is because this is not 'please fix my typo' sort question

Comment: Unlike C, there is no standard defining things like memory layout for JavaScript. Not only is there not a single answer overall, in some cases there may not be a single answer for a single engine, because JITs can compile and evaluate code differently depending on how it's used. In *some* cases, functions that are only used as functions are probably only stored as functions, without any specific space allocated for storing the properties. (This is my dodging a complicated questions.)

Comment: Functions have properties and methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: I don't understand question 2. There are no statements inside the hash map, and they're not executed.

Comment: MAYBE, function is an invoked constructor of an function object.. this comment will be flagged maybe

Comment: @HankyPanky I gave a correct answer. I think when you see how unfulfilling a correct answer looks, it makes sense why the question is bad.

Comment: Ahh... are you trying to interpret the contents of `{ ... }` the same way in both cases? That might be misleading you. The syntax of a function body is entirely different than an object literal; they just happen to use the same outer delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every object in javascript has properties (key-value pairs identified by strings or symbols) and it has [internal slots](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots).

The function object `name` is stored in the same format as the `person` object, but their internal slots differ.

- `person`'s properties are `firstName`, `lastName`, `age` and `eyeColor`, each holding the respective primitive value
- `person`'s internal slots are (amongst others):

  - `[[prototype]]`, pointing to `Object.prototype`
- `name`'s properties are `name`, `prototype` and `length` (as typical for [`Function` instances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function))
- `name`'s internal slots are (amongst others):

  - `[[prototype]]`, pointing to `Function.prototype`
  - `[[ECMAScriptCode]]`, pointing to the code of the function
  - `[[Environment]]`, pointing to the scope the closure was created in

<sub>Disclaimer: That's only how it behaves, engines may implement this however they want. Still, it serves well as a mental model, and it's important to understand that objects have a layer below the publicly visible properties.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Functions are objects, in that they can have properties and methods. Unlike objects, they can also be called and will always return a result.

Note that the ECMAScript (i.e. JavaScript) [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) describes how [Function objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) should behave rather than underlying implementation, so the in-memory representation of the object will depend on implementation.

Regarding 2: Note that the full text of a Function might be stored in the `functionBody` property, however the body of a Function does not have to be JavaScript. It could be native code, for example, that is not meaningful to return in a string.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the body of a function does not have to be JavaScript? I interpret the question to be: "Describe the nature of a JavaScript function..." which means, by definition, the body is JavaScript. Are you referring to whether the implementer (browser, server, etc.) stores the body as text or some other form within memory?

Comment: See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.24 - "a function contains executable code and state that determine how it behaves when invoked. _A function’s code may or may not be written in ECMAScript._" (emphasis mine). E.g. host methods like document.getElementById - if you call `.toString()` you'll get `[native code]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do regular JavaScript coding, I don't think you really need to worry about how the function is stored by the browser or server or whatever. I do think you are misunderstanding the object-nature of a function. The lines of code inside the function are not individual parts of a hash map. Rather (and this only begins to touch on the concept), a function can have properties with names and values just like a regular object can have such properties. The following code demonstrates this.

```js
var myFunc = function() {
  var x = "hello".toUpperCase();
  document.write('<p>' + x + '</p>');
};

myFunc.favoriteColor = "red";

myFunc(); // runs the function and shows the text "hello"
document.write("<p>" + myFunc.favoriteColor + "</p>"); // shows the text "red"
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to 1. is: It depends on the implementation.

The 2nd question doesn't make any sense.

I think you are looking at the syntax, and assuming that because the way data is declared, and the way functions are declared, that a function can be treated as data in the language.
This is not the case.

There are languages where this IS the case. Lisps and Prolog being the most common examples.  see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity

Comment: Sorry, hopefully this clears up my question - say I have an if statement inside my function... will that be stored in a property accessible through one of its properties?