# If closures act like objects, are they objects? (It doesn't seems like)

Tags: javascript

First of all, I want to tell all viewers that I am not asking how closures work, I understand them, but, I am wondering what their data type should be.

By operation,  a closure is like a record storing a function together with an environment. So, I tried to do this in JS:

```
"use strict";

function printString(x){
    var string = "hello " + x;

    return function(){
        console.log(string + ' how are you');
    };
}

var myClosure = printString("Myname");
document.getElementById("testElement").textContent = typeof myClosure;
```

Now, if `myClosure` has data type of `function`, then how is it able to 'remember' or store the local variables created at the time of execution? Typically, objects do this kind of stuff. So, shouldn't the closure be an object?

Comment: Objects are poor man's closures and closures are poor man's objects.

Comment: everything in Javascript is an object, even a function

Comment: [This article goes into details on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: Your premise, that the closure is either a function or an object, is wrong:

"In JavaScript every function is actually a Function object". Source:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: Apart from functions already *being* objects, why do you think they would need to be objects to store their scope? Strings store their characters, do they need to be objects for that?

Comment: Have a look at [JavaScript - Functions as objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35761676/1048572)

Comment: @KWeiss—I don't think that MDN reference is correct. A "Function object" should be one that inherits from Function.prototype, but the only requirement for an object to be a function is that it implements an internal `[[Call]]` method (per [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-function) and [*typeof*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-typeof-operator)). So host objects, for example, can be Objects and functions but not be instances of Function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on MDN:

> A closure is a special kind of object that combines two things: a
>   function, and the environment in which that function was created. The
>   environment consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the
>   time that the closure was created.

The closure in your example consists of 2 components:

1. A simple function object `myClosure`
2. Captured environment (scope) where this function was defined. This environment gives you access to `var string` variable. It's an engine  implementation (based on ecma standard) how these references are stored and developer has no way to influence that, just use it.